# Need Help Understanding How Coarse-Grain Mapping Works in Parallel

Tags: c, mpi

This is a somewhat difficult question to ask (as I'm dealing with an abstract problem), so I will do my best to describe it here.

I am working on C code that is capable of solving LU decomposition in parallel. My code uses a 2D coarse grain parallel algorithm structure to solve multiple parts of a given matrix at the same time. My code is listed below, and I am using [this](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs554/fa2013/notes/06_lu_8up.pdf) PowerPoint as a general reference (see slide 19 and 17). The code works perfectly fine with serial outputs (N = 1) and r x r square matrix definitions.

```
/*

use calloc to assign heap memory for 2D arrays

*/

// mapping algorithim goes here?

                /* Implement a 2D - coarse grain LU decomposition solving algorithim */
                for (int k = 0; k < r; k++) {
                     MPI_Bcast(&arrayInFunction[k][j], r, MPI_LONG_DOUBLE, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                    if (k < r) {
                        for (int i = k + 1; i < r; i++) {
                            lowerTArray[i][k] = arrayInFunction[i][k] / arrayInFunction[k][k];
                            printf("This is lower %lf \n", lowerTArray[i][k]);
                        }
                    }
                     MPI_Bcast(&lowerTArray[i][k], r, MPI_LONG_DOUBLE, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                    for (int j = k + 1; j < r; j++) {
                        for (int i = k + 1; i < r; i++) {
                            arrayInFunction[i][j] = arrayInFunction[i][j] - lowerTArray[i][k] * arrayInFunction[k][j];
                            printf("This is upper %lf \n", arrayInFunction[i][j]);
                        }
                    }
                }

/*

Print the LU matrix

*/
```

*Where `arrayInFunction` is essentially the A matrix.*

I am having a little bit of difficulty understanding how to implement the coarse - grain mapping expression shown in slide 17 of the [previous link](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs554/fa2013/notes/06_lu_8up.pdf). Note that the 2D grain "task formula" is defined as  `(n/k)^2/p` , which makes perfect logical sense, but **I am unsure how to implement this successfully into the LU decomposition code**. Without this mapping algorithm, my code is basically just an overcomplicated serial solution  with extra MPI communication on multiple processes (not good).

I would like someone to share an example on how to implement mapping / task management to LU decomposition algorithms. Or, I would also accept an answer that points out where / how (in the code above) I need to define and implement `(n/k)^2/p` (assuming the solution is that simple ;)  ). I have read conceptual explanations, but have not been able to successfully implement this idea.

Thanks all,

Comment: As a general comment, I realize that this question may be a little short sighted. I am trying to teach this content to myself, so I occasionally run into a case problem that ends up being much bigger than expected (such as this). I will leave this thread open for anyone who wishes to provide additional help.

Answer (score 1):

LU decomposition requires considerable reformulation to make it work in parallel.

1. At the very least you have to block the outer loop so that you synchronize only every so many pivots.
2. Unfortunately that's not enough: you have to distributed your matrix cyclically over the processes.

There is a reason that there are basically only 2 or 3 packages on earth that implement this.

Read: https://theartofhpc.com/istc/parallellinear.html#LUfactorizationinparallel

Comment: It certainly seems like I have tipped the iceberg of something much bigger than expected here.  May I ask what you are referring to when we talk about "2-3 packages ... that implement this"?

Comment: Scalapack (old, but still more or less the standard), PLapack (has not been updated in forever), Elemental (much more modern but of unclear state), maybe there is something in the Trilinos library. Ok, that's 3 or 4.

Comment: I've taken note and will explore these packages. I will leave this thread open for now, in case additional responses come in...Thanks for the help.